# How searching works in GNOME 3.8?

Tags: gnome3

How does searching work in Gnome 3.8.2? Why when I search 'power' (Press Super key and type 'power' one-by-one) I get **LibreOffice Impress**? And 'po' returns **Document Viewer**, **Rhythmbox**, **SElinux Troubleshooter**, **OpenJDK Policy Tool**, **Software**, **Automatic Bug Reporting Tool**, even **Mouse & Touchpad** and **Notifications** comes before **Power**, why is this?

Comment: It's probably searching the descriptions as well as the names. "Impress" might contain "PowerPoint" in it's description.

Comment: Could you also explain _how_ you are searching? Using the menu? The command line?

Comment: @terdon This is searching in the overview mode, as accessed by pressing the Super ("Windows") key or mousing to the top left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the new Gnome search functionality still can use some work. It seems to do well suggesting frequently used programs, and separates the actual programs from settings.
That said, some guesses for why those results come up for 'po'... took some thinking and Googling. Most were not obvious to me, either.

- Document Viewer: Postscript
- Rhythmbox: Podcast
- SElinux Troubleshooter: Policy?
- OpenJDK Policy Tool: Policy
- Software: Pretty broad... maybe searches software for 'po', or could be "Popular"
- Automatic Bug Reporting Tool: maybe just 'po' in "Reporting"?
- Mouse & Touchpad: Pointing device, Pointer, etc.
- Notifications: Popup?